# How to Improve technical skills while working in support projects

Tags: java

I am  working on a support java project, which was fully developed years ago and now in maintenance phase. I just completed one year in it but don't feels like I gain any technical skill. We spent most of the time in checking server logs and making minor changes. 
As now a days most of the project are in maintenance phase it's really difficult to get core development work. So how can I improve my technical skills while working in support?

Comment: Do you work for HCL/Infosys? :)

Comment: No. I work in India based support company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you see the code right, try to optimize the code in some parts, work on adding additional functionality and stuff. You could try freelancing to improve these skills, if you cant do it at work.

Comment: We don't have much scope for optimization and adding new functionality.it's small application used in universities.I am inclined towards android application development so tried freelancing but no luck as I don't have prior experience.

Comment: Then I think you should start freelancing, since you are mostly out of options at work

Comment: You could just take up a project and work on it. Like develop an app on your own and things, If you are interested in android, try making an app, and try getting it onto android market, it'd help you in getting freelance projects.

Comment: I got my first assignment in Android :) it's small piece of application and I am doing it for free. Lets see how things go.

Answer (score 2):

You can improve technical skills by reading books and practicing the skills you want to acquire.  So long there is work to be done on a computer, it can be automated.  Try to script everything.  Use new scripting languages to force yourself to learn them.  Write programs to track and analyze bugs.  Write regression tests to cover bugs that you fix.

In part, you will be doing these things because you want to help the company and your team be more productive.  In part, it will be to learn and fight the boredom of repetitive tasks.

Comment: Sounds good. Will get do something different than my mundane tasks. Will defiantly give a try. Thanks.